# Why does `"foo".bar = 42;` throw `TypeError` in strict mode in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typeerror, ecmascript-5, primitive

According to the ES5.1 spec, the program `"use strict;" "foo".bar = 42;` causes a `String` object to be created, assigns to a property on it, and then throws the object away, resulting in no observable effects - including any exceptions.  (The absence of effect can be confirmed by trying it in an ES5-compatible JS implementation like that in Opera 12.)

In modern JS implementations, it throws a `TypeError` instead—try it:

```js
"use strict"; "foo".bar = 42;
```

I am pretty sure the new behaviour is mandated by the ES6 spec, but despite reading the relevant sections several times I cannot see where it is specified that `TypeError` be thrown.  In fact, [the key parts](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-putvalue) appear to be unchanged:

> 6.2.3.2 PutValue (*V*, *W*)#
>
> 1. ReturnIfAbrupt(*V*).
> 2. ReturnIfAbrupt(*W*).
> 3. If Type(*V*) is not Reference, throw a **ReferenceError** exception.
> 4. Let *base* be GetBase(*V*).
> 5. If IsUnresolvableReference(*V*) is true, then
>
>    - …
> 6. Else if IsPropertyReference(*V*) is true, then
>
>    - a. If HasPrimitiveBase(*V*) is true, then
>
>      - i. Assert: In this case, *base* will never be null or undefined.
>      - ii. Set *base* to ToObject(*base*).
>    - b. Let *succeeded* be ? *base*.[[Set]](GetReferencedName(*V*), *W*, GetThisValue(*V*)).
>    - c. ReturnIfAbrupt(*succeeded*).
>    - d. If *succeeded* is false and IsStrictReference(*V*) is true, throw a **TypeError** exception.
>    - e. Return.
> 7. …

Where does the spec (ES6 or later) mandate throwing `TypeError`?

Comment: I'm not seeing it in [Annex C](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-of-ecmascript), either.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect this isn't actually in the spec at all.

Comment: Here’s where it made it into V8, with no references as usual: https://codereview.chromium.org/408183002/ Looking at others now.

Comment: My expectation is that the `ToObject` would explicitly return a non-extensible `String`, thus `[[Set]]` would return false and step 6 would throw, but I don't actually see it defined that the string object is non-extensible.

Comment: @Paulpro: “`ToObject` is just copying the `[[Extensible]]` attribute” – are you referring to implementations here? They don’t even do a `ToObject`, so it’s not too confusing.

Comment: @Paulpro: Creating a string object, setting it inextensible with `Object.preventExtensions`, and trying to set a property on it in strict mode produces a different error message for me, one mentioning "object is not extensible". It doesn't seem to be going through an object at all for the case in the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess it's here:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-ordinaryset

> 9.1.9.1. OrdinarySet (O, P, V, Receiver)
>
> [...]
>
> 4.b. If Type(Receiver) is not Object, return false.

(Previously called [[Set]], in [ES6 §9.1.9](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-set-p-v-receiver).)

Although `PutValue` promotes the `base` to an object, it doesn't do the same with the receiver -- `GetThisValue(V)` is still called on the original `V` (with a primitive base). So, `GetThisValue` returns a primitive, `OrdinarySet.4b` fails to assign a freshly created `ownDesc` and returns `false`, and this in turn causes `PutValue.6d` to throw a TypeError, provided the reference is strict.

The corresponding part of V8 seems to follow the same logic:

```
Maybe<bool> Object::AddDataProperty(....
  if (!it->GetReceiver()->IsJSReceiver()) {
    return CannotCreateProperty(...
```

https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/3b39fc4dcdb6593013c497fc9e28a1d73dbcba03/src/objects.cc#L5140

Comment: It shouldn't reach there, because `ownDesc` should be undefined.

Comment: So what? Step 3 doesn't return.

Comment: Nice find, that does look right to me. It'll walk up the prototype and eventually hit the top level, create a data descriptor, and try to set it on the receiver, which is still the primitive.

Comment: @georg: True. I don't see where strict mode would come into things, though.

Comment: There is no mention of strict mode. If this would throw an error, then it should throw it without strict mode too, which is not true

Comment: Yes it would be good to expand this to mention `6.d`, though that was already included in the question.

Comment: It looks like [12.3.2.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation) is where the spec says the reference is a strict reference, and [6.2.3.2 6.c.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-putvalue) throws a TypeError for a strict reference.

Comment: It's weird that this doesn't seem to be covered in Annex C. Annex C is only informative, but still. Weird.

Answer (score 5):

@georg’s answer seems to be the right ES6+ interpretation, but it looks like the behaviour isn’t new, either. From [ES5.1 PutValue](https://es5.github.io/#x8.7.2):

> 4. Else if IsPropertyReference(V), then
>
>    a. If HasPrimitiveBase(V) is false, then let put be the [[Put]] internal method of base, **otherwise let put be the special [[Put]]
>    internal method defined below**.
>
>    b. Call the put internal method using base as its this value, and passing GetReferencedName(V) for the property name, W for the value,
>    **and IsStrictReference(V) for the Throw flag**.

and in the referenced [[Put]]:

> 7. Else, this is a request to create an own property on the transient object O
>
>    a. If Throw is true, then throw a TypeError exception.

It feels like I’m probably misreading something… but what else could the rather pointed “this is a request to create an own property on the transient object O” be referring to?

Comment: This is an excellent observation.  I am not quite sure how I overlooked this when checking the ES5.1 spec—but it looks like the Opera 12 devs did too.