# Which object does not have `hasOwnProperty` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, strict, hasownproperty

With some values, calling `hasOwnProperty` throws an error.

Let's check the following code:

```
null.hasOwnProperty('bar') // Error
undefined.hasOwnProperty('bar') // Error
(0).hasOwnProperty('bar') // Returns false
```

Are there any other variables rather than `null` and `undefined` that throws an error when calling with `.hasOwnProperty`?

The same question for setting an object's property:

```
null.bar // Error
undefined.bar // Error
(0).bar === undefined // Returns true
```

=========

Another case where it throws an error in my Node.js environment:

In a browser

```
'use strict';
(0).bar = 0; // Nothing happens
```

In Node.js v.10.3.0:

```
(0).bar = 0; // Nothing
'use' strict';
(0).bar === undefined; // Returns true
true.bar === undefined; // Returns true
''.bar = '';// STILL NOTHING HAPPENS
(0).bar = 0; //TypeError: Cannot create property 'bar' on number '0'
(true).bar = true; // TypeError: Cannot create property 'bar' on boolean 'true'
```

========

Eventually, I found *[Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22482737/1398479)*:

```
if (obj instanceof Object) obj.hasOwnProperty(...) // Or set a property on it
```

This solution totally fulfills my needs.

Comment: `null` and `undefined` are not **variables**, they are **types**.  Conceptually, it would be impossible for something that doesn't exist (`null`) or something that isn't defined (`undefined`) to have any properties.

Comment: Any object you derive from `null` has not `hasOwnProperty` method, you can create the method, though.

Comment: hasOwnProperty requires an Object (or something that inherits from Object). To see what are *not* objects, see here: https://www.quora.com/Is-everything-an-object-in-Javascript

Comment: Not sure what `(0).bar = 0` has to do with your original question…? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682661/why-does-foo-bar-42-throw-typeerror-in-strict-mode-in-es6, anyway.

Comment: @Ry- I am recursively set property on object. I just want to cover all cases can ever happen.For example, `recursivelySet(obj, path, value)`. If someone passes `recursivelySet(1, 'foo.bar', 0)`,I want the function to detect this case and do nothing.

Or more obivious case, `recursivelySet({foo: 1}, 'foo.bar', 0)`

Comment: Are you sure you don’t want your function to throw on a task that doesn’t make sense? That’s what exceptions are for.

Comment: I want to recursively set something on `req.body`, and it can be anything because it is passed from client. I think it would be better if the server returns `parameter error` in the next middleware, rather than throws `Server Internal Error`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR;**

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` can be called directly on

- `Object.prototype`,
- The subset of objects which have `Object.prototype` in their inheritance chain and don't redefine `hasOwnProperty` in either the inheritance chain or on the object, and
- BigInt, Boolean, Number, String and Symbol primitive values. Calling it on primitive values is generally superfluous however as

  ```
    (primitiveValue).hasOwnProperty(propertyName)
  ```

  always rerturns `false` - primitive values do not have own properties.

---

**Data Types**

JavaScript currently supports eight different data types in the [ECMAScript 2020](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values) specification:

> BigInt (introduced in ECMAScript 2020), Boolean, Null, Undefined, Number, String, Symbol (new in ECMAScript 2015)
> and Object.

The first seven of these are primitive values rather than object values - including `null` which is of data type Null. (Yes, `typeof null` returns "object" instead of "null", but this is an artifact of early JavaScript engine design that can't be fixed because it would break the web.)

**Number, Boolean and String**

Values of type Number, Boolean and String are automatically converted into "wrapper" object instances of global constructors `Number`, `Boolean` and `String` respectively when used with property value lookup syntax.

Hence

```
(1).hasOwnProperty("MAX_SAFE_INTEGER")
```

returns false because the property is inherited from `Number.prototype`. Similarly `hasOwnProperty` calls on Boolean values return false because Boolean wrapper objects don't have any innate own properties themselves. But

```
("hello folks").hasOwnProperty("length");
```

returns`true` because "length" is an own property of the String wrapper object.

**Undefined and Null**

Primitive values of data type Undefined (`undefined`) or Null (`null`) are not converted to wrapper objects and generate syntax errors when attempting to call `hasOwnProperty` on them as a method:

```
    (undefined).hasOwnProperty("example")  // TypeError
    (null).hasOwnProperty("example")       // TypeError
```

**Symbol and BigInt**

Symbol and BigInt data type values have separate treatment - they were both introduced following a decision that new data types in ECMAScript would not have object wrappers.

Effectively this means that the JavaScript engine internally implements the syntax of applying  `Symbol.prototype` and `BigInt.prototype` methods to `symbol` and `bigint` data types respectively, but only allows read access to prototyped methods and properties - any attempt to set a property on a `symbol` or `bigint` data type generates an error.

- Neither the `Symbol` nor `BigInt` global functions allow the use of `new` before calls to them.
- `Symbol` acts a factory function and returns a new symbol value.
- `BigInt` is a type conversion function to convert strings and numbers to `bigint` data type.
- Unlike older object wrappers for `boolean`, `number` and `string` data types, attempting to **set** properties on a `symbol` or `bigint` data type never quietly succeeds.

**Object**

Objects ( of data type Object) generally inherit `hasOwnProperty` from `Object.prototype`. This inheritance can fail if either `hasOwnProperty` is redefined somewhere later in the inheritance chain (**not a good idea**), or if the object was created with `null` in its inheritance chain before reaching `Object.prototype`.

The easiest way to create an object with `null` at the start of its inheritance chain is by calling

```
Object.create( null);
```

Extending such an object will also create objects which don't inherit from `Object.prototype` and so can't use `hasOwnProperty`.

Note that applying `instanceof Object` to an object whose prototype chain does not include `Object.prototype` returns `false`. Do not use `instanceof` to determine Object data type.

#### Wrapper objects and strict mode.

In early versions of JavaScript, setting properties on wrapper objects automatically created from primitive values was syntactically correct and did not generate errors. *However*, the wrapper object was discarded as soon as the wrapper object expression was evaluated. Trying to look up a custom property in later code fails because a new, different wrapper object, lacking the custom property, is used for the lookup.

Strict mode generates an error if an attempt is made to assign a property value to any primitive value.

#### Possible Check Function

```js
const checkOwnProperty = (obj, propertyName) =>
    (obj && (typeof obj == "object" || typeof obj == "function") &&
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call( obj, propertyName))
    ? true : false;

// Test:
var o = {name: "foo"};
console.log (  "name " + checkOwnProperty( o, "name"))
console.log (  "foo " +  checkOwnProperty( o, "foo"))
console.log (  "0 " +  checkOwnProperty( 0, "foo"))
```

`CheckOwnProperty` returns a boolean reflecting if the first argument is of Object data type **and** has an own property with the same name as the second argument. It returns false for all primitive values.

Comment: Please recheck the ''.bar = ''; case shown in the OP >> With node v14.0.0. This does not throw error.

Comment: there is `BigInt` type not mentioned in the answer

Comment: @transang  I didn't notice in 2018: "use strict"; must be the first statement/expression in JavaScript source to be recognized. Moving it to the first line (and correcting the string syntax) generated an error trying to add a property to a string in both Node 10.15.3 and  Node 14.2.0 when tested.

Comment: you are correct. I have tested and successfully reproduced. It eventually throws error if 'use strict' is placed at the begin

Answer (score 2):

[Using hasOwnProperty as a property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty#Using_hasOwnProperty_as_a_property_name):

```
var foo = {
  hasOwnProperty: function() {
    return false;
  },
  bar: 'Here be dragons'
};

foo.hasOwnProperty('bar'); // always returns false

// Use another Object's hasOwnProperty
// and call it with 'this' set to foo
({}).hasOwnProperty.call(foo, 'bar'); // true

// It's also possible to use the hasOwnProperty property
// from the Object prototype for this purpose
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, 'bar'); // true
```

Also take care to the latest [draft](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.prototype.hasownproperty):

> When the hasOwnProperty method is called with argument V, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let P be ? ToPropertyKey(V).
> 2. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
> 3. Return ? HasOwnProperty(O, P).
>
> **NOTE**
>
> The ordering of steps 1 and 2 is chosen to ensure that any exception that would have been thrown by step 1 in previous editions of this specification will continue to be thrown even if the this value is undefined or null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call it on any variable which is not `undefined` nor `null`.

```js
console.log([1].hasOwnProperty(0)); // true
console.log([1,2].hasOwnProperty(1)); // true
console.log([1,2].hasOwnProperty(2)); // false

console.log({ a: 's'}.hasOwnProperty('a')); // true
console.log({ b: 's'}.hasOwnProperty('a')); // false
console.log({}.hasOwnProperty('a')); // false

console.log((555).hasOwnProperty('a')); // false
console.log((false).hasOwnProperty('a')); // false
console.log((true).hasOwnProperty('a')); // false
console.log(("skjhkdasj").hasOwnProperty('a')); // false
console.log((1.045).hasOwnProperty('a')); // false
// console.log((null).hasOwnProperty('a')); // error
// console.log((undefined).hasOwnProperty('a')); // error
```

Comment: Not in `Object.create(null)`, which is an object without the `Object` prototype.

Comment: It is quite common to create objects using `Object.create(null)` instead of `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

YOU ARE CORRECT.  IT EXIST ON EVERYTHING BUT UNDEFINED AND NULL

```js
class Vehicle {
  constructor(name, type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
  }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  constructor(color) {
    super()
    this.color = color
  }
}

console.log(new Car().hasOwnProperty('color'))
console.log(new Car().hasOwnProperty('name'))

console.log(new Vehicle().hasOwnProperty('color'))
console.log(new Vehicle().hasOwnProperty('name'))

function foo() {}
foo.hasOwnProperty('bar')
true.hasOwnProperty('bar')

const symbol = Symbol();
Symbol.hasOwnProperty('bar')
symbol.hasOwnProperty('bar')

Boolean.hasOwnProperty('bar')
String.hasOwnProperty('bar')
Array.hasOwnProperty('bar')
Number.hasOwnProperty('bar')
Object.hasOwnProperty('bar')
Car.hasOwnProperty('bar');
[].hasOwnProperty('bar');
"".hasOwnProperty('bar');
(1).hasOwnProperty('bar');

//null.hasOwnProperty('bar')
//undefined.hasOwnProperty('bar')
```

Comment: I think your array and number problems come from incorrect syntax (lack of semicolons, lack of parentheses). Try `;[].hasOwnProperty('bar')` and `1..hasOwnProperty('bar')`.

Comment: And maybe “you can’t call it on a class” came from mistakenly using `Foo` instead of `Car`?

Comment: @Ry I fixed the class to be OK.

Comment: @Ry- whooo! never had the array on a second line do that.  wow!  learn something new every day.  Thanks!

Comment: You can call it on a number. `1.hasOwnProperty` is parsed as the number `1.` (a trailing decimal point), then just a random `hasOwnProperty`. Use `1..hasOwnProperty` or `;(1).hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: I already fixed that one. And add symbol/Symbol too, and string.

Comment: Your answer **You can't call it on undefined, null, or a number** is not correct. The code in my question says **I call it on a number**. Morever, You list `undefined, null, number` and another list of many. Is there any other type exist?

Comment: OK.  I surrender.  I can't find anything it doesn't exist on.

Comment: It looks like `Obeject.create(null)` does not have `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: Doesn’t that return null?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check for the existence of properties, and not necessarily what their value might be, then you have two safe options: hasOwnProperty() and the in operator. The hasOwnProperty() property method should be used if you want to detect own properties only. If you want to test property existence and don’t care if it’s an own property or an object property, then the in operator is the one to use.

[reference for more information click here](https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2010/07/27/determining-if-an-object-property-exists/)

Comment: **safe options**: it throws error (my question), it does **not safe**, I think

Comment: about the function error 
A handler function with request.query.hasOwnProperty('whatever') will result in a "request.query.hasOwnProperty is not a function" error.

Changing to Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(request.query, 'whatever') work

This is expected. nodejs modified the query object returned by the querystring module such that it uses a null prototype, and therefore does not inherit the base properties and methods of ordinary Object instances.

Comment: did you check the code? `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(null, 'whatever')` throw `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Comment: please give me more details ... you may also refer to this link 

[link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object/29721434